# css, javascript: random image loader with array removes the first part of my variable how to fix this?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, random

I'm trying to set a random image background with css and javascript to a div, but when I load the random image on google chrome it does not work

I tried to do all image urls in variables but this does not work.

does anyone know why it is changing my code and why it is not working

**code that loads the random image**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var image1 = "images/image1.png";
    var image2 = "images/image2.png";
    var image3 = "images/image3.png";
    var image4 = "images/image4.png";

  var imageURLs = [
       "image1"
     , "image2"
     , "image3"
     , "image4"
  ];
  function getImageTag() {
    var img = '<div class="pdiv2" style="background-image: url("';
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * imageURLs.length);
    img += imageURLs[randomIndex];
    img += '")"></div>';
    return img;
  }

</script>
```

**where the image is printed**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        document.write(getImageTag());
    </script>
```

**output when I do with google chrome inspect, edit as html**

```
<div class="pdiv2" style="background-image: url(" image3")"=""></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with your code. First, you need to remove the `"` as you're using variables:

```
var imageURLs = [
  image1,
  image2,
  image3,
  image4
];
```

Second, you also need to remove the double-quotes around the `url()` that you manually inject. Your final function should look like this:

```js
var image1 = "images/image1.png";
var image2 = "images/image2.png";
var image3 = "images/image3.png";
var image4 = "images/image4.png";

var imageURLs = [
  image1,
  image2,
  image3,
  image4
];

function getImageTag() {
  var img = '<div class="pdiv2" style="background-image: url(';
  var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * imageURLs.length);
  img += imageURLs[randomIndex];
  img += ')"></div>';
  return img;
}

console.log(getImageTag()); // For StackOverflow output
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `"` it's not a variable so!

var imageURLs = [
           image1
         , image2
         , image3
         , image4
      ];

Edit:

Function:

```
function getImageTag() {

  var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * imageURLs.length);
  var randomIndex = imageURLs[randomIndex];
  var img = '<div class="pdiv2" style="background-image: url('+randomIndex+')"> </div>';
  return img;
}
```

Comment: tnx but this does not change the output `<div class="pdiv2" style="background-image: url(" afbeeldingen="" image3.png")"=""></div>`

Comment: Ok i hope it helps. I have made a little simpler